# Need to install SVN 1.7.5 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, svn, deployment, capistrano

Alright, this issue is pretty long. It all started with Capistrano(v2.14.2/v2.15) integration with SVN. After few initial hurdles, I at last am in almost the last step in which the SVN compatibility issue arose.

**SVN Repository:**
Ubuntu - 13.04
SVN Version - 1.7.5

**Server to be deployed with Capistrano:**
Ubuntu - 14.04
SVN Version - 1.8.8

Now when I try to deploy with valid credentials, I am unable to and I get the following error.

> ** [54.201.104.110 :: err] svn: E215004: Authentication failed and interactive
>   prompting is disabled; see the --force-interactive option
>    ** svn: E215004: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'URL'
>    ** svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.

Then after some search, I found that the culprit might be the version difference between the repository server and the deployment server. The version details are mentioned above.

I do not want to touch the repository server and upgrade it to 1.8.8. I would like to downgrade the svn version of deployment server to 1.7.5. I am able to find some solution on the basic issue of downgrading but they aren't working. So here I am, posting the issue about the "specific" version downgrade of SVN.

I am relatively new to Capistrano as well as all of the above mentioned tasks. Forgive my ignorance and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm :(

I was setting my scm_username in the deploy.rb file but was entering password in the prompt. Once I set my password also in the file, it started working! Mysterious Capistrano!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the errors:

```
E215004: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'URL'
E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
```

This issue is not related to Subversion version in any way. The root cause is invalid user credentials.

Comment: I have put it as 'URL' in the question to not to disclose it. Credentials are 100% correct as I am able to login to the repository through browser. :(